# Deploying Rails on Elastic Beanstalk Permissions Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Still pretty fresh to AWS and couldn't seem to find documentation for this. Seems to be just an issue of permissions, but not sure how I even go about setting up the proper permission?

```
INFO: createEnvironment is starting.
INFO: Using elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-622149014054 as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
INFO: Created security group named: sg-5f68323b
INFO: Created load balancer named: awseb-e-p-AWSEBLoa-O3Y0LNU3E9S1
INFO: Created security group named: awseb-e-p43bijndhr-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-A24GYF35IF1G
INFO: Created Auto Scaling launch configuration named: awseb-e-p43bijndhr-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration-UGEGZJI5PT83
INFO: Created Auto Scaling group named: awseb-e-p43bijndhr-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-WFP5QBMKUMS2
INFO: Waiting for EC2 instances to launch. This may take a few minutes.
INFO: Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:us-west-2:622149014054:scalingPolicy:c1980398-1613-4ea4-900a-480ab626a92b:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-p43bijndhr-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-WFP5QBMKUMS2:policyName/awseb-e-p43bijndhr-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleDownPolicy-9LKH88SW3Y1I
INFO: Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:us-west-2:622149014054:scalingPolicy:c1f7dc16-0f91-4a15-afba-d977e6ac6ebc:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-p43bijndhr-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-WFP5QBMKUMS2:policyName/awseb-e-p43bijndhr-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleUpPolicy-18R5SX1VFZFO1
INFO: Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-p43bijndhr-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmLow-1HEIUVF80C258
INFO: Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-p43bijndhr-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh-V8O9P9GIKLC8
ERROR: [Instance: i-6ade9bae] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...d!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/angular-ui-router-rails-0.2.15/vendor/assets/javascripts/angular-ui-router.js

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace).
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_asset_compilation.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
INFO: Added EC2 instance 'i-6ade9bae' to Auto Scaling Group 'a3ab9ac4-bc4c-4efc-95d2-87d1e1b38eac'.
INFO: Adding instance 'i-6ade9bae' to your environment.
INFO: Application available at fourleafapp-dev3.elasticbeanstalk.com.
ERROR: Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.

ERROR: The operation timed out. The state of the environment is unknown.
```

Comment: try to create the environment online. the command line is known to be problematic.

Comment: i get the same exact error deploying online @Tal

Comment: anything more interesting in eb-activity.log?

Comment: nah pretty much the same @tal